# Grammar for discard expression in PLY(EBNF) is causing binary expression to be treated as a unary expression

Tags: python, parsing, ply

I am writing a parser (using PLY) for a subset of python. It includes: `int`, `name`, `add`, `unarysub`, `assignments`, and `function_calls`.

So far I have the following grammar:

```py
# Grammar for P0:
# statements := statement+
# statement := simple_statement
# simple_statement := assignment | d_expression
# assignment := NAME ['=' expression]
# d_expression := expression
# expression := sum
# sum := sum '+' term | term
# term := factor
# factor := '+' factor | '-' factor | primary
# primary: primary '(' [arguments] ') | atom
# atom := INT | NAME
# arguments := args | empty
# args := arg | arg ',' args
# arg := expression
```

It works as intended for pretty much all the cases I need. However, I am having trouble with discard expressions(`d_expression`) above. Python supports discard expressions. For eg, python treats both `x = 1 + 2` and `1 + 2` as valid program. The former gets an Assign node in python AST, while the latter gets an Expr node(which is discarded, hence the name discard expression).

I am trying to emulate this behavior in my parser, but when implementing this feature, my parser treats `1 - 2` as a list of two Expr nodes(`Expr(Constant(value=1)`, `Expr(UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=Constant(value=2)`). This is an incorrect behavior and it should throw a syntax error as I don't have a `expression MINUS expression` in my grammar. I am not sure where I am going wrong, any help is appreciated.

Below is the code implementation of my parser:

```py
class MyParser:
    tokens = MyLexer.tokens

    precedence = (
        ('left', 'PLUS', 'MINUS'),
        ('right', 'UMINUS'),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.lexer = P0Lexer()
        self.parser = yacc.yacc(module=self)

    def p_module(self, p):
        '''
        module : statements
        '''
        p[0] = Module(body=p[1])
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_statements(self, p):
        '''
        statements : statement
                   | statement statements
        '''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = [p[1]]
        else:
            p[0] = [p[1]] + p[2]
        for i in p[0]:
            logging.info(ast.dump(i))

    def p_statement(self, p):
        '''
        statement : simple_statement
        '''
        p[0] = p[1]
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_simple_statement(self, p):
        '''
        simple_statement : assignment
        '''
        p[0] = p[1]
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))
    
    def p_assignment(self, p):
        '''
        assignment : NAME EQUALS expression
        '''
        p[0] = Assign(targets=[Name(id=p[1], ctx=Store())], value=p[3])
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    # def p_d_expression(self, p):
    #     '''
    #     d_expression : expression
    #     '''
    #     p[0] = Expr(value=p[1])
    #     logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_expression(self, p):
        '''
        expression : sum
        '''
        p[0] = p[1]
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_sum(self, p):
        '''
        sum : sum PLUS term
            | term
        '''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = p[1]
        else:
            p[0] = BinOp(left=p[1], op=Add(), right=p[3])
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_term(self, p):
        '''
        term : factor
        '''
        p[0] = p[1]
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_factor(self, p):
        '''
        factor : MINUS factor %prec UMINUS
               | primary
        '''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = p[1]
        else:
            if p[1] == '+':
                p[0] = UnaryOp(op=UAdd(), operand=p[2])
            else:
                p[0] = UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=p[2])
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_primary(self, p):
        '''
        primary : primary LPAREN arguments RPAREN
                | atom
        '''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = p[1]
        else:
            p[0] = Call(func=p[1], args=p[3])
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_arguments(self, p):
        '''
        arguments : args 
                 | empty
        '''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = p[1] if p[1] is not None else []
        else:
            p[0] = []
        for i in p[0]:
            logging.info(ast.dump(i))

    def p_args(self, p):
        '''
        args : arg
            | arg COMMA args
        '''
        if len(p) == 2:
            p[0] = [p[1]]
        else:
            p[0] = [p[1]] + p[3]
        for i in p[0]:
            logging.info(ast.dump(i))

    def p_arg(self, p):
        '''
        arg : expression
        '''
        p[0] = p[1]
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_atom(self, p):
        '''
        atom : INT
             | NAME
        '''
        if isinstance(p[1], int):
            p[0] = Constant(value=p[1])
        else:
            p[0] = Name(id=p[1], ctx=Load())
        logging.info(ast.dump(p[0]))

    def p_empty(self, p):
        '''
        empty :
        '''
        pass

    def p_error(self, p):
        if p:
            logging.error("Syntax error at '%s'" % p.value)
        else:
            logging.error("Syntax error at EOF")
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Apologies if I missed it, but where is the definition of `compound_statement`? That would be useful to look over. (My thought process: languages like C, C++, Java, and JavaScript use `;` in expressions interpreted as statements, so `a - b` couldn't be interpreted as the expression statements `a` and `-b`. In Python, newlines play a similar role. Perhaps your parser is permitting adjacent expressions with no separator?)

Comment: I am sorry I removed the compound_statement. It is not needed for this usecase.

Comment: (1) In your code only the commented out part creates an "Expr" object. (2) Your output shows an "Expr" object containing a constant and another "Expr" object. I think this output is not possible with the shown code, even with the commented out part being active.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, that's because I removed it from the `simple_stmt` production so that I could use it to test other case. The issue is solved now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue here is that

```
statements := statement+
```

is your culprit. This allows you to place any two `statement`s side-by-side and have it be considered a `statements`. If that's the case, then `1 - 2` is indeed a valid `statements`, because, as you noted, this can be broken apart into the statements `1` and `-2`, each of which is a discard-expression.

It might be helpful to look at other programming languages as an example to see how to resolve this. In languages like C, C++, or Java, expressions can be made into statements because there's a grammar rule to the effect of

```
statement := expression ;
```

with the `;` serving as a separator. That means that if you were to find something like

```
1 + 2 2 + 3;
```

in a C/C++/Java program, it would be a syntax error because while `1 + 2` and `2 + 3` are expressions, those expressions aren't statements without a semicolon after them. On the other hand, it would be legal in those languages to write

```
1 + 2; 2 + 3;
```

on one line, and there's a clear delimiter between the two expressions making up the two statements.

Now let's look at Python. Python will not allow you to write

```
1 + 2 2 + 3
```

and have it count as two expressions. Why not? Well, if you check out [the Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), you can see that in the way it parses a series of simple statements into a `simple_stmts` expression. (Python uses a parsing expression grammar rather than a CFG, so the syntax is a bit different.)

```
simple_stmts:
    | simple_stmt !';' NEWLINE
    | ';'.simple_stmt+ [';'] NEWLINE
```

In other words, a `simple_stmts` is either

1. A `simple_stmt` followed by a newline, or
2. A series of `simple_stmt`s, separated by semicolons, and followed by a newline.

Each of these rules gives clear delimiters between expressions, either newlines or semicolons (or both).

So in this sense, I suspect the issue is fundamentally not one about drop expressions but rather about how you allow multiple statements to be separated from one another. Requiring some sort of delimiter - say, a newline or semicolon - after each expression used as a statement should fix this.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I didn't realize that issue was with the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @templatetypdef. I was allowing two expression without a separator.

I solved it by introducing this production:

```
simple_stmts:
    | simple_stmt !';' NEWLINE  # Not needed, there for speedup
    | ';'.simple_stmt+ [';'] NEWLINE
```